# MouseMotionListener events on sub-figures - GEF

Tags: java, mouseevent, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I'm using a parent draw2d figure which contains several sub figures (buttons. using Toolbar layout) which registered to MouseMotionListener and do some action (lets say 'enterAction') on mouse enter do something else on mouse exit ('exitAction').

From some reason, 'exitAction' is invoked while pointing one of the sub buttons. 
I have tried to register recursively all the children of the parent figure to MouseMotionListener events, and although it "solved my issue" ('exitAction' was fired but I manage to caught it in the button's 'enterAction' and handled it) - another issue occurred: The button's 'actionPerformed' event (I have added the button an ActionListener) is not fired (or it is, but handled somewhere I cannot find...).

Any help? :\ 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to solve in general, because in draw2d mouse events don't propagate through elements as in html.

You can for example move the listener up to the canvas:

```
import org.eclipse.draw2d.ActionEvent;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.ActionListener;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.Border;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.Button;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.ColorConstants;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.Figure;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.FigureCanvas;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.Layer;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.LineBorder;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.ScalableLayeredPane;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.XYLayout;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.geometry.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseMoveListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class HHH {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final FigureCanvas canvas = new FigureCanvas(shell);
    final ScalableLayeredPane pane = new ScalableLayeredPane();
    pane.setScale(1.5f);

    canvas.setContents(pane);

    final Layer layer = new Layer();
    layer.setLayoutManager(new XYLayout());
    pane.add(layer);

    final Figure container = new Figure();
    container.setOpaque(true);
    container.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.lightBlue);
    container.setLayoutManager(new XYLayout());
    layer.add(container, new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100));

    final Button b = new Button("Push");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            MessageBox box = new MessageBox(shell);
            box.setText("button pressed");
            box.open();
        }
    });
    container.add(b, new Rectangle(10, 10, -1, -1));

    canvas.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {

        Border oldBorder = null;
        boolean over = false;

        @Override
        public void mouseMove(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent e) {
            final Rectangle containerBounds = container.getBounds().getCopy();
            container.translateToAbsolute(containerBounds);

            if (containerBounds.contains(e.x, e.y)) {
                // simulate enter container figure
                if (!over) {
                    oldBorder = container.getBorder();
                    container.setBorder(new LineBorder());
                    over = true;
                }
            } else {
                // simulate exit container figure
                if (over) {
                    container.setBorder(oldBorder);
                    oldBorder = null;
                    over = false;
                }
            }
        }

    });

    shell.setSize(500, 500);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

}

}
```